# mask tensor with 0 according to value at some specific index at the inner-most dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say I have a tensor **A** of shape `[x, y, z]`.

For the sake of explanation, let's assume that **A** is of shape `[2,4,3]`:

```
[[[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[4,4,4],[1,1,1]], [[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]]
```

I want to "mask" this tensor such that,

> if elements at index 1 at the inner most dimension equal to **2**, then the surrounding tensors should not change, otherwise they are all change to 0.

In this example, the tensor should become

```
[[[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]], [[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[0,0,0]]]
```

What is the right way in tensorflow to perform this operation? I have tried several approach and was limited by the fact that working with tensors that contain variable-sized tensor is painful in tensorflow.

The only solution that I can think of is to use `map_fn` to iterate through the tensor (till the -2 dimension). But using `map_fn` is tricky and will hurt performance because

1. If I have tensors of higher rank (say 4+), it is required to use several `map_fn` insides `map_fn`.
2. `map_fn` cannot run on GPU and can hurt performance, especially in case of large dataset.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```python
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[4,4,4],[1,1,1]], [[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,3,3]]])

x_idx1 = x[..., 1]
mask = tf.cast(tf.equal(x_idx1, 2), tf.int32)
mask = tf.expand_dims(tf.cast(mask, x.dtype), -1)
masked_x = x * mask

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(masked_x))
    # [[[1 2 3], [2 2 3], [0 0 0], [0 0 0]]
    #  [[2 2 2], [2 2 2], [2 2 2], [0 0 0]]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, enjoy (tested):

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant( [[[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[4,4,4],[1,1,1]], [[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]] )
a2 = a[ :, :, 1 ]
b = tf.where( tf.equal( a2, 2 ), tf.ones_like( a2 ), tf.zeros_like( a2 ) )[ :, :, None ]
c = tf.tile( b, [ 1, 1, a.get_shape()[ 2 ].value ] )
d = a * c

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run ( d ) )
```

Outputs:

> [[[1 2 3]
>     [2 2 3]
>     [0 0 0]
>     [0 0 0]]
>
> [[2 2 2]
>     [2 2 2]
>     [2 2 2]
>     [0 0 0]]]

---

Most efficient, one-liner version, with ideas from [Aldream's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50153061/4320693) and [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50152743/mask-tensor-with-0-according-to-value-at-some-specific-index-at-the-inner-most-d/50153089?noredirect=1#comment87323935_50153089), albeit much less clear to read:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant( [[[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[4,4,4],[1,1,1]], [[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]] )

b = a * tf.cast( tf.equal( a[ ..., 1 ], 2 ), a.dtype )[ ..., None ]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run ( b ) )
```

Outputs:

> [[[1 2 3]
>     [2 2 3]
>     [0 0 0]
>     [0 0 0]]
>
> [[2 2 2]
>     [2 2 2]
>     [2 2 2]
>     [0 0 0]]]

Comment: Beat me by some seconds. :) No need for tiling though as TF broadcasting does the job well for the multiplication. Wondering about the performance of `tf.where()` vs `tf.equal()`...

Comment: Yeah I just saw it, nice competition! :) I also have `tf.equal()` so the question is `tf.where()` vs. `tf.cast()`, which the latter probably wins... You're right about broadcasting, thought it more readable this way, but you're right.

Comment: @Aldream inspired by your comment, I've added a one-liner version :)

Comment: Thanks for correcting my comment! As for the rest, it's a matter of personal taste I guess ;)

Comment: Wow, didn't know that `[..., None]` has the effect of `expand_dims`; Cool!